# A simple question about autonomous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'=f(x)$, $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ an open set, $0\in A$, $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ and $f(0)=0$.

Let $\varphi(t,x)$ be the maximal solution passing by the point $(0,x)$, with $t\in I_x$ and $I_x$ denotes the maximal interval.

I think it is true that the funcion $\phi:y\in A\longrightarrow \phi(y)=\varphi(t,y)$ is continuous (here $t$ is fixed). But I can not prove it.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. How do you define continuity? For example, with $\dot{x} = x$, we have $\phi(t,y) = ye^t$, which is continuous for a fixed $t$, but for any $y_1 \neq y_2$ there is some $t$ such that $|phi(t,y_1)-\phi(t,y_2)| > 1$.

Comment: $t$ is fixed point

Comment: I think you also need some uniformity conditions on I_x$ for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $y$.

Comment: We can asumme $I_x=(a,\infty)$, with $a<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
\dot x=f(x),\quad x(0)=x_1
$$
and
$$
\dot x=f(x),\quad x(0)=x_2.
$$
Let $\phi(t,x_1)$ and $\phi(t,x_2)$ be the solutions of these problems respectively.

Put
$$
v(t)=\phi(t,x_1)-\phi(t,x_2).
$$

You have 
$$
v(t)\leq v(0)+L\int_0^t v(\tau)d\tau,
$$
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant. By Grownwall's inequality you finally get
$$
v(t)\leq v(0)e^{Lt},
$$ 
which proves that the solution depends continuously on the initial condition.

But since you assume that $f\in\mathcal C^1$, you can actually prove that your solution is also $\mathcal C^1$ in the initial condition The proof, however, a little more involved, but can be found in almost any ODE textbook.

Comment: Another nice proof uses the fact that the solutions are fixed points of a Lipschitz mapping, and that the mapping is continuous (or differentiable) in the initial condition.